# connect form page on wordpress with php file

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, postgresql

I created form on one page in my wordpress:

```
<form action="scores_send.php" method="post">
<strong>Date: </strong><input type="date" name="date" /><br /> 
<strong>TEAM 1:</strong>
Player 1.: <input type="text" name="team1_player1" /><br /> 
Player 2.: <input type="text" name="team1_player2" /><br /> 
<strong>TEAM 2:</strong>
Player 1.: <input type="text" name="team2_player1" /><br /> 
Player 2.: <input type="text" name="team2_player2" /><br /> 
<strong>SCORE:</strong>
Team 1. <input type="number" name="score_team1" min="0" max="5"/> : <input type="number" name="score_team2"  min="0" max="5"/> Team 2.<br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Add" /> 
</form>
```

And also I wrote php code which connect to my external (no-wordpress) postgres database (connection parameters in code are not true) and insert information from form to one table:

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['date']; 
$t1p1 = $_POST['team1_player1']; 
$t1p2 = $_POST['team1_player2'];
$t2p1 = $_POST['team2_player1']; 
$t2p2 = $_POST['team2_player2'];
$score1 = $_POST['score_team1'];
$score2 = $_POST['score_team2'];

if($date and $t1p1 and $t1p2 and $t2p1 and $t2p2 and $score1 and $score2) { 

    $connection = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=scores user=user password=pass")
    or die('Brak polaczenia z serwerem PostgreSQL'); 
    $db = @pg_select_db('scores', $connection) 
    or die('Nie moge polaczyc sie z baza danych'); 

    $team1 = @pg_query("INSERT INTO scores.games (score_team1, score_team2, datetime, team1_player1, team1_player2, team2_player1, team2_player2) VALUES ('$score1', '$score2', '$date', '$t1p1', '$t1p2', '$t2p1', '$t2p2'"); 

    if($team1) echo "Scores added."; 
    else echo "ERROR! Scores not added"; 
     pg_close($connection); 
} 
?>
```

I tried 2 ways:
1. to create template php file in folder of my theme and
2. to paste this code to content editor in wordpress (using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/)

and both ways is not working. I changed part "action" in , but maybe wrong.

Comment: use( $date && $t1p1 && $t1p2 && $t2p1 && $t2p2 && $score1 && $score2)

Comment: instead of "if($date and $t1p1 and $t1p2 and $t2p1 and $t2p2 and $score1 and $score2)" or how? I don't know PHP enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just change your action of your form to : http://yoursite.com/scores_send.php

make sure that your scores_send.php is on the root of your installation.

So, your form look like :

```
<form action="http://yoursite.com/scores_send.php" method="post">
```

Comment: I tried your way and after click "Add" in form browser displayed blank page and in database nothing was added. Maybe it is problem of my PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://example.com/page-slug/ in form action

Where page-slug is the slug of another page create by make scores_send.php as template.It will post all form value to score_send.php.From where you can proceed further to insert into external DB.

```
<form action="http://example.com/page-slug/" method="post">
```

Comment: Also I tried your way and it the same situation like in Sunil Chaudhary's methods - blank page and nothing was added to my database. :(

Comment: First you need to check get_header() and get_footer() function in your target page, if it is not there it make your page blank.Another you need to test 'echo' and also need to test 'echo' post value to cross check about target value and whether your form is actually posting or not.If that way you can not get result, try Ajax Method for post form value and from there insert into database.